# how to use SHCreateStreamOnFileEx to create a file with a long UNC path

Tags: windows, api, unc

When I use SHCreateStreamOnFileEx to create a stream with a long UNC path (WCHAR, like \?\UNC\localhost\long.......long.....path\abc.txt), I got error "0x80070003 The system cannot find the path specified. ".

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759866(v=vs.85).aspx,

*Remarks
The SHCreateStreamOnFileEx function extends the semantics of the STGM flags and produces the same effect as calling the **CreateFile** function.*

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx,
*lpFileName [in]
In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters. **To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters**, call the Unicode version of the function and prepend **"\?\"** to the path. For more information, see Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces.*

Anyone know how to let SHCreateStreamOnFileEx support long UNC path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `CreateFile` function requires you to convert `\\server\share\path` to `\\?\UNC\server\share\path`, that's two backslashes in the beginning.  If that doesn't work, then `SHCreateStreamOnFileEx` doesn't support the long paths.